# how to delay() qtip() tooltip to be loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, qtip

I Load this way:

```
$('.selector').each(function(){
$(this).qtip({
     content: { url: '/qtip.php?'+$(this).attr('rel')+' #'+$(this).attr('div'), text:'<center><img src="/images/loader.gif" alt="loading..." /></center>'  },

     show: { delay: 700, solo: true,effect: { length: 500 }},
     hide: { fixed: true, delay: 200 },

     position: {
     corner: {
        target: 'topRight',
        tooltip: 'left'
                }
                },
                show: {
          // Show it on click
         solo: true // And hide all other tooltips
      },
     style: {
       name: 'light',
       width: 730,border: {
         width: 4,
         radius: 3,
         color: '#5588CC'
      }    
       } 
   });

});
```

And that looks like if there is a thelay cause of the effect. but qtip.php it's loaded with no delay which is what I really want (to reduce unneeded requests)

Can I delay 300ms before loading qtip.php?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set it to use a custom event, then trigger the event after a timeout. The [hoverIntent plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent) might help, if you want to wait until the mouse stops.

### Using hoverIntent:

```
$(selector).hoverIntent(function() {
    $(this).trigger('show-qtip');
}, function() {
    $(this).trigger('hide-qtip');
}).qtip({
    // ...
    show: {
        when: { event: 'show-qtip' }
    },
    hide: {
        when: { event: 'hide-qtip' }
    }
});
```

If you want to make hoverIntent wait longer before triggering, you can give it a configuration object with an `interval` property:

```
$(selector).hoverIntent({
    over: showFunction,
    out: hideFunction,
    interval: 300 // Don't trigger until the mouse is still for 300ms
});
```

### Without a plugin (I haven't tested this):

```
(function() { // Create a private scope
    var timer = null;
    var delay = 300; // Set this to however long you want to wait

    $(selector).hover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $this.trigger('show-qtip');
        }, delay);
    }, function() {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }).qtip({
        // ...
        show: {
            when: { event: 'show-qtip' }
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Tested the no plugin option and no succes :( but thanks a lot! i'll give it some time ;)

Comment: OK, i was about to try the hoverintent solution and question, do i need both functions you posted? or only last one? thanks!

Comment: @Toni: You only need one of them. Which one is up to you :) The difference (other than leaving out the `qtip` call and using function names instead of literals) is that in the second example, the user would have to hold their mouse still for 300ms, and in the first example, it's whatever the default time is (10ms I think).

Comment: @MatthewCrumley great answer. I have never thought about using a custom event.

Answer (score 2):

Here I just created another param and it's more simple to use, I have tested this in qtip1(not sure about qtip2)

```
$('.qtip').qtip({
    show: { 
        when: 'mouseover',
        //customized param, when 'mouseout' the qtip will not shown and delay will clean
        cancel : 'mouseout',
        delay: 500
    }
});
```

To add this param, you need to modify the code of function assignEvents() in qtip:

```
function assignEvents()
{
    ...

    function showMethod(event)
    {
        if(self.status.disabled === true) return;

         // If set, hide tooltip when inactive for delay period
         if(self.options.hide.when.event == 'inactive')
         {
            // Assign each reset event
            $(inactiveEvents).each(function()
            {
               hideTarget.bind(this+'.qtip-inactive', inactiveMethod);
               self.elements.content.bind(this+'.qtip-inactive', inactiveMethod);
            });

            // Start the inactive timer
            inactiveMethod();
         };

         // Clear hide timers
         clearTimeout(self.timers.show);
         clearTimeout(self.timers.hide);
// line : 1539         

// Added code
--------------------------------------------
         // Cancel show timers
         if(self.options.show.cancel)
         {
             showTarget.bind(self.options.show.cancel,function(){
                 clearTimeout(self.timers.show);
             });
         }
--------------------------------------------

         // Start show timer
         self.timers.show = setTimeout(function(){ self.show(event); },self.options.show.delay);
      };
```

Answer (score 2):

For `qtip2` there is parameter, called `show` while initializing the plugin, which represents time in milliseconds by which to delay the showing of the tooltip when the `show.event` is triggered on the `show.target`.

For example:

```
/*This tooltip will only show after hovering the `show.target` for 2000ms (2 seconds):*/

jQuery('.selector').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'I have a longer delay then default qTips'
    },
    show: {
        delay: 2000
    }
});
```