# jquery/css: I want to change the bgcolor of row only after hovering for 1 or 2 seconds. How to achieve this?

Tags: jquery, css, hoverintent

I want to change the bg-colour of row only after hovering(meaning...I have a tool-tip on each row. I want to change the colour only after viewing a tool-tip text)  for 1 or 2 seconds. How to achieve this? With my current code, the colour changes for all rows wherever my mouse-cursor touches after 1 second de

With my current code, the colour changes for all rows wherever my mouse-cursor touches after 1 second

*Current code:*

```
$('#table_id tr td').hover(function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).parent('tr').addClass('blueBgColor');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z494a/

Comment: $(self).parent('tr').siblings().removeClass('blueBgColor'); if you want to remove bg color for the rest of the rows, after hover on specific row...

Comment: The problem here is: When we take the cursor from all the rows fastly(without hovering for some time). After certain time, it will change all rows to blue.

Comment: From what I realized from various sources, it is not possible to implement this requirement using  setTimeout or delay. We have to use hoverIntent to achieve this. But I am not sure how to implement hoverIntent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used setTimeout function to achieve your task...

```
var timer, thisid;
 $('td').mouseenter(function(){
    thisid = $(this);
     timer = setTimeout(function(){
       $(thisid).parent('tr').addClass('blueBgColor');
    },2000);  
}).mouseleave(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

and for your reference check this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7X67L/17/)

Comment: @user3910012 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440207/how-to-delay-qtip-tooltip-to-be-loaded

Comment: @user3910012 check this QA .. It may helpfull for your

Comment: we will have the problem when we have multiple rows in a table.        The problem here is: When we move the cursor across all the rows fastly(without hovering on any row for some time). After certain time, it will change all rows to blue

Comment: @KishorePaparthi Hi friend I forgot to mension you.. i updated the code and now its bg color will change after hovering 2min >.  this code satisfy your requirement .If it is helpfull you may accept this answer now

Answer (score 0):

Kishore you want all work done by us .. 
is so hard to increase timeout to 2000 ms or 3000ms whatever you want ???

kamesh solution is very nice .. [**look at this jsfiddle:**](http://jsfiddle.net/CristiC777/7X67L/20/)

you can move your cursor over the rows .. only if you stay 2 seconds on a row, will change his background.

```
  thisid.parent('tr').css({'background-color':'#00F','color':'#fff'});
      },2500);
```

Comment: I believe, you did not read the question correctly. Its not merely increasing the time. Kamesh answer is really nice. He updated the code by clearout the timeout on mouseleave. Which is a good idea.